# From Default Perl on OSX, How To Unzip To Folder?

Tags: macos, perl, zip, unzip, compression

I'm trying to avoid having to include other libraries and keep this simple on OSX, **using the default Perl that ships with OSX since Snow Leopard**. I'm also trying to **avoid shelling out to Bash** to run the unzip. I found [this example](https://gist.github.com/eqhmcow/5389877) almost works, but dies on this line:

```
my $fh = IO::File->new($destfile, "w") or die "Couldn't write to $destfile: $!";
```

with this error:

> Couldn't write to /tmp/mytest/Install Norton Security.localized//: Is a directory at test7.pl line 42.

Previously, I zipped the folder "Install Norton Security.localized" to mytest.zip and stuck it in /tmp. I then created a directory /tmp/mytest. Then, I ran this script with

`unzip("/tmp/mytest/mytest.zip","/tmp/mytest");`

I also did a lint syntax check on the script and it came back okay -- didn't warn me about missing libraries like many other zip libraries for Perl.

What do you suggest is the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This routine works on older OSX and doesn't involve as many lines of code. It also handles subfolders.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip qw(:ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS);

my $sSource = "/tmp/mytest.zip";
my $sDest = "/tmp/mytest";

x_unzip($sSource,$sDest);

sub x_unzip {
    my ($zip_file, $out_file, $filter) = @_;
    my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($zip_file);
    unless ($zip->extractTree($filter || '', $out_file) == AZ_OK) {
        warn "unzip not successful: $!\n";
    }
}
```

SOURCE: https://gist.github.com/mshock/4156726